# Why does Galadriel allow the 3 elven rings to be created?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-rings-of-power

In *Rings of Power* S01E08, after Galadriel finds out Sauron's true identity, why does she still allow for the 3 elven rings to be forged? She must surely be suspicious about Sauron's involvement in the creation of the rings.

Is she not aware that the rings will eventually be under the control of the one ring? Or is she more concerned about keeping the elves in Middle Earth?

Comment: The show removes Galadriel's primary Second Age motivations - pride and greed - and as a result certain actions she takes start to not make any sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is she not aware that the rings will eventually be under the control of the one ring?

Canonically, *nobody* was aware of this (emphasis mine):

> But they were, **all of them**, deceived, for another ring was made. In the land of Mordor, in the fires of Mount Doom, the Dark Lord Sauron forged **in secret** a master Ring, to control all others.

I must confess I haven't watched *Rings of Power* yet, but the very fact you're asking this question implies that there's no evidence to the contrary (i.e. that Galadriel, at that point in time, *was* aware of the One Ring's existence and/or function).

Comment: Just to confirm, this is true in The Rings of Power too. As of the series finale only the three elven rings have been forged, and no one knows about Sauron's plans for the One Ring (or the rings for dwarves and humans for that matter).

Comment: I’ve upvoted this answer and yet I think the asker makes a good point that this doesn’t address. Namely, even though Galadriel has no knowledge of the forging of the One Ring, if she has discovered Sauron is/was a servant of Morgoth, why is she not more concerned about anything he has been involved with?

Answer (score 3):

Elrond has informed her prior to the revelation of who Sauron is, that the elves require Celebrimbor to make a device to allow the elves to continue to live in Middle Earth. After finding out that Sauron has tampered with the device/rings, she is left no option but to modify Sauron's plan to create 2 rings and instead create 3 rings. If she orders them to stop making the rings, then the elves must leave middle earth and Sauron will take over. If she has them create a third ring then:

1. The elves can stay in Middle Earth
2. She has a chance of stopping Sauron now that they can stay in Middle Earth
3. They won't be playing exactly into Sauron's plans of creating only two rings